# Getting the latitude and longitude for a set of Node's

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid

in my **android application** when i capture a picture the , **GPS** read info of my location  (lat/long) , I need to get the **lat/long** for my town and insert it to my database , I download my region file by mean of **JSOM** software supported by www.openstreetmap.com the file was in osm extention , my mind tell me that i need to write a program to parse this file (raw data) and insert the whole **node's** (id + lat +long + other info ) to my database is that the best solution ,becasue time killing me ! .

**In other word my Question is how to extract the data in file.osm**

Note:every Node has it's unique ID

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/36814/getting-the-latitude-and-longitude-for-set-of-nodes

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what your actual problem is. Your smartphone should already be capable of obtaining lat and lon via the integrated GPS device.

Do you need the name of the town for the current position? In that case you can use [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) and run a simple *reverse* geocoding query.

Do you need the position of a specific town? In that case use [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) with a regular geocoding query.

Comment: here's my situtaion , i'm working on project that recognise a building from Image captured from Android smartphone ,what I want is benefit from the GPS to bound the search space of my building so  I need to get my town building location (lat/long) i.e(in openStreetMap node attribute ) I try QGIS but it give me every thing id , name etc but not the latitude and longitude which is my Interest

Comment: I can't imagine that QGIS won't give you the coordinates. But if you have the node ID you can use OSM's [API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) to retrieve the corresponding coordinates of a given node.